# How to mock Python classes when nested several dependencies deep

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing, mocking

If I have the following architecture...

**Please note the edits below. It occurred to me (after some recent refactoring) that there are actually three classes in three different files. Sorry that the file/class names are getting ridiculous. I assure you those are not the real names. :)**

```
main_class.py

class MainClass(object):
    def do_some_stuff(self):
        dependent_class = DependentClass()



dependent_class.py

class DependentClass(object):
    def __init__():
        dependent_dependent_class = DependentDependentClass()
        dependent_dependent_class.do_dependent_stuff()



dependent_dependent_class.py

class DependentDependentClass(object):
    def do_dependent_stuff(self):
        print "I'm gonna do production stuff that I want to mock"
        print "Like access a database or interact with a remote server"

class MockDependentDependentClass(object):
    def do_dependent_stuff(self):
        print "Respond as if the production stuff was all successful."
```

and I want to call `main_class.do_some_stuff` during testing but, during its execution, I want instances of `DependentDependentClass` replaced with `MockDependentDependentClass` how can I do that pythonically using best practices.

Currently, the best thing I could come up with is to conditionally instantiate one class or the other based on the presence/value of an environment variable. It certainly works but is pretty dirty.

I spent some time reading about the unittest.mock and mock.patch functions and they seem like they might be able to help but each description that I could wrap my head around seemed to be a little different than my actual use case.

The key is that I don't want to define mock return values or attributes but that I want the namespace changed, globally, I guess, such that when my application thinks it is instantiating DependentClass it is actually instantiating MockDependentClass.

The fact that I can't find any examples of anyone doing exactly this means one of two things:

1. It's because I'm doing it in a very dumb/naive way.
2. I'm doing something so genius no else has ever encountered it.

... I assume it's number 1...

Full disclosure, unit testing is not something with which I am skilled. It's an effort that my internal tools development team is trying to catch up to step our game up a bit. It's possible that I'm not thinking about testing correctly.

Any thoughts would be most welcome. Thank you, in advance!

**SOLUTION!!!**

Thanks to @de1 for the help. Given my *clever* architecture shown above the following accomplishes what I want.

**The following code is located in `main_class.py`**

```
import dependent_class
from dependent_dependent_class import MockDependentDependentClass

with patch.object(dependent_class, "DependentDependentClass", MockDependentDependentClass):
    main_class = MainClass()
    main_class.do_some_stuff()
```

The code seems to (and hell if I know how it's doing this) manipulate the namespace within the module `dependent_class` so that, while inside the `with` block (that's a context manager for anyone who is hung up on that part) anything referring to the class object `DependentDependentClass` will actually be referencing `MockDependentDependentClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mock module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) does indeed seem to be a good fit in this case. You can specify the mock (your mock) to use when calling the various `patch` methods.

If you are importing only the class rather than the module you can patch the imported DependentDependentClass in DependentClass:

```
import .DependentClass as dependent_class
from .DependentDependentClass import MockDependentDependentClass

with patch.object(dependent_class, 'DependentDependentClass', MockDependentDependentClass):
  # do something while class is patched
```

Alternatively:

```
with patch('yourmodule.DependentClass.DependentDependentClass', MockDependentDependentClass):
  # do something while class is patched
```

or the following will only work if you are accessing the class via a module or import it after it is being patched:

```
with patch('yourmodule.DependentDependentClass.DependentDependentClass', MockDependentDependentClass):
  # do something while class is patched
```

Just bare in mind what object is being patched, when.

Note: you might find it less confusing naming your files in lower case, slightly different to the embedded class(es).

Note 2: If you need to mock a dependency of a dependency of the module under test then it might suggest that you are not testing at the right level.

Comment: Hmmm. Neither one seems to accomplish it for me. In the second example I assume that `dependent` as used in the `with` statement was supposed to be `dependent_class`?

Comment: Yes, that's fixed. Not sure why it wouldn't work. It basically replaced `DependentClass` within the `DependentClass` module (for the duration of the context).

Comment: My check consists of simple print statements in the `__init__()` methods of each class. One prints "REAL" the other prints "MOCK." With both approaches you showed I get "REAL."

Comment: Are you sure you are instantiating `DependentClass` and in this case `MainClass` within the with statement?

Comment: I am instantiating `MainClass` inside the with statement. `DependentClass` is being instantiated within `MainClass`'s `__init__()` in a different file. I think that the problem might be that the namespace change does not carry over to the other file. Maybe the example wasn't clear. Each mention of `something.py` was an indication of a separate source file.

Comment: I added another option. I suspect it's the way you are importing the DependentClass which would resolve it before it is being patched.

Comment: Please see the edits to the OP. There are actually three files each with a different class. I tried modifying your third example accordingly (`main_class` replaced with `DependentDependentClass`). No exceptions are being raised but I'm still seeing "REAL". I'm doing this inside a Flask app, I hope that isn't messing with my context somehow.

Comment: Actually, I think it worked! I'll posted my "aha" moment for clarity in the OP. Thank you, so much, @de1!!!

Comment: I think it would have saved time if you posted a complete simple example including imports that you are actually testing ;-)